# Why None is printed when a slice of the list is sorted

Tags: python, sorting, slice

The following code

```
   L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
   print(L[2:8].sort(reverse=True))
```

prints `None` while I expect it to print `L = [1, 2, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 10]`

1. Why is it so?
2. If that's not the way to sort part of the list (a slice), what is, given that I need to do it in the same list, not create another one?

Comment: Because `list.sort` works in-place. Use `sorted(L[2:8], reverse=True)` instead.

Comment: @keepAlive so the correct code would be ```L[2:8] = sorted(L[2:8], reverse=True)```?

Comment: @alekscooper In general you can do either `L = sorted(L, reverse=True)` or more directly `L.sort(reverse=True)`, just don't do `L = L.sort(reverse=True)`. But here you want to combine it with slicing and there's only `L[2:8] = sorted(L[2:8], reverse=True)` which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
L[2:8] = sorted(L[2:8], reverse=True)
print(L)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 10]
```

This should solve the issue

This works because when `L[2:8].sort(reverse=True)`, it attempts to sort the slice `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]` in reverse order. But since `sort()` changes the original list which here it is not able to and `None` gets returned instead.

But `sorted()` does not effect the original list and needs to assigned manually to the position.

Comment: The code is correct but the explanation is worded in a confusing way. `.sort` always returns `None`, even when it successfully sorts an original list.